# Powershell Use Mapped Drive As Root Path

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have directories that are too long (hitting the 260 character limit), so I'm trying to map the path to a lettered drive (T:).

The way that I am finding the path name's that are too long is by returning the .TargetName of the error records of a search on the root directory of the file share. So the long path name is in $errorRecord.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
foreach ($record in $errorRecord)
{
New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root ($record.CategoryInfo).TargetName -Persist

$path = "T:\"

$ACLs = get-acl -path $path -recurse | 
ForEach-Object { $_.Access  } | 
Where {$_.IdentityReference -notlike "*BUILTIN*" -and $_.IdentityReference -notlike "*NT AUTHORITY*"}
Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs)
{
    $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference
    Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path "C:\Permissions2.csv"
}
Remove-PSDrive T
}
```

So that gets the file path, sets it to T:\ and then (is supposed to) get the information out of the recursive folders beneath the T:\ drive.

What is output however, is the full path name of the T:\ drive, with its permission information, but doesn't go below that point - presumably because of the character limit.

How do I change the ouput to be only the lettered "T:\" drive so that it will hopefully dig deeper?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the long path on C is 300 characters. Use subst like this to create a new root:

```
PS C:\> subst t: c:\foo\bar\<250 chars>\ # new win32 logical drive
PS C:\> new-psdrive temp filesystem -root t:\ # new powershell drive
PS C:\> cd temp:
PS temp:\> cd blah\blurgh\<remaining path>\
```

Make sense?

Comment: Kind of. With that method you'd have to find out manually the character limited length path, and put it in though?